# High Charts not honouring the label format

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I am using high charts to build a graph, which has multiple y axis and x axis date time based. But I see whatever format I am giving high charts for X axis it does not honour it the date is consecutive (example : july 01, july 02, july 03).The X axis is always giving format :  **date. month**, although I specified **date/month**.

Can anyone help me with the config options.

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Snow depth at Vikjafjellet, Norway'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Irregular time data in Highcharts JS'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                month: '%e/%b'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Date'
            }
        },
        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: 'Snow depth (m)'
            },
            min: 0
        }, {
          opposite: true,
            title: {
                text: 'Snow height (m)'
            },
            min: 0
        }],
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f} m'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Winter 2012-2013',
            // Define the data points. All series have a dummy year
            // of 1970/71 in order to be compared on the same x axis. Note
            // that in JavaScript, months start at 0 for January, 1 for February etc.
            yAxis: 1,
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(2016, 7, 01), 4],
                [Date.UTC(2016, 7, 02), 5],
                 [Date.UTC(2016, 7, 03), 15]
            ]
        }, {
            name: 'Winter 2013-2014',
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(2016, 7, 01), 44],       
                [Date.UTC(2016, 7, 02), 5],
                [Date.UTC(2016, 7, 03), 135]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your `dateTimeLabelFormats` to,

```
dateTimeLabelFormats: {
   day: '%e / %b',
   week: '%e / %b'
}
```

Will resolve the issue.

**Working JSFiddle Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/6jo3gvfa/

Hope this helps!.